# `snyk-scm-contributor-count` failing to retrieve project list from github

Tags: github-enterprise, snyk, sast

I am trying to retrieve a contributor count using Snyk's `snyk-scm-contributor-count` to count the list of contributors. However when I run this:
`snyk-scm-contributor-count github-enterprise --token TOKEN  --url HOST_URL`

I receive the error: "Failed to retrieve project list from GitHub Enterprise" and all of my information comes up as 0. Is there any information in the token settings that I would need to change

I have tried putting quotations around my URL, trying different command options, trying a specific repository and none of them have yielded results.

Comment: Did you try this admin:read:org, repo (all)